# How to extract the URL from the last column of of a table, where the row contains certain words, using Mechanize

Tags: python, mechanize, mechanize-python

I'm trying to automate some tedious web tasks for an internal ticketing system I maintain.
There is a page, with an automatically generated table full of mail server configurations.  Each row is for a different mail server, and the last column for each row contains 2 links, the first of which I need to be able to extract, if the first column in that row matches specific words.  I'm trying to do this in python using mechanize.

the table is called like this:

```
<table id="pop-mail-servers-table" class="aui aui-table-rowhover">
```

and the row in question looks like this:

```
            <tr>
                    <td>
                        <span class="mail-server-name">
                            <strong>testhandler-mcfake</strong>
                        </span>
                                                        <div class="description"></div>
                                                </td>
                    <td>
                        <ul class="item-details">
                            <li>
                                <dl>
                                    <dt>Host:</dt>
                                    <dd><span class="mail-server-host">fake.mail.server</span></dd>
                                </dl>
                                <dl>
                                    <dt>Username:</dt>
                                    <dd><span class="mail-server-username">testhandler-mcfake</span></dd>
                                </dl>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <ul class="operations-list">
                            <li><a id="edit-pop-10550" href="UpdatePopMailServer!default.jspa?id=10550">Edit</a></li>
                            <li><a id="delete-pop-10550" href="DeleteMailServer!default.jspa?id=10550">Delete</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

So basically if the first column contains "testhandler-mcfake", then I want to extract that Edit URL from the last column in that same row.

Is this a thing?  Can it be done?

Answer (score 1):

[PyQuery](http://packages.python.org/pyquery/) allows you to select HTML elements, using jQuery-like syntax.